# Use draggable after DOM update

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

the current DOM is like this:

```
<div id="image_list">

</div>
```

after an event this will update to :

```
<div id="image_list">
   <img class="dragable-img" src="image1.png" />
   <img class="dragable-img" src="image2.png" />
   <img class="dragable-img" src="image3.png" />
   <img class="dragable-img" src="image4.png" />
 </div>
```

Now there is a js in the page that is supposed to handle dragging

```
$('.dragable-img').draggable({
        revert: true,
            handle: 'img',
            containment: "#content-body", 
            scroll: false
 }).disableSelection();
```

**Obviously, it is working before updating the DOM and it is not working after it.
So, What am I missing here**?

Comment: how are you manipulating the dom? using ajax? or is it all clientside?

Comment: @wirey~ I update the div content when a drop-down is changed using Ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) function - it will trigger after every ajax call on the page

```
$('#image_list').ajaxComplete(function(){
    $('.dragable-img',this).draggable({
        revert: true,
        handle: 'img',
        containment: "#content-body", 
        scroll: false
    }).disableSelection();
)};
```

The better way would be inside your $.ajax success function to call draggable again

```
$.ajax({
    url:yoururl
    success: function(){
       //do what you need.. update/add to your dom 
       //then call draggable on your elements
       $('.dragable-img').draggable({
           revert: true,
           handle: 'img',
           containment: "#content-body", 
           scroll: false
       }).disableSelection();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if this works..

```
$('#image_list').on('draggable', '.dragable-img' , function(){
   return {
            revert: true,
            handle: 'img',
            containment: "#content-body", 
            scroll: false
   }

}).disableSelection();
```

If this does not work .. try using `.draggable()` after the elements are inserted into the **DOM**.